# Android: File name not changing programmatically

Tags: android, android-file, android-external-storage, android-music-player, android-internal-storage

I tried to change the file name of a song by programmatically by using the code

```
File from = new File(filedirectory,currentName+type);
                File to = new File(filedirectory,newName+type);
                from.renameTo(to);
```

But after executing the code the current file is not show in the music list, also the new one is not showing in the list.

The file path and the file name are:

```
filedirectory:  /storage/emulated/0/media/audio/music/
newName:  aaaa.m4a
currentName:  bbb.m4a
```

In the manifest I given all the necessary permission and am executing the code in Kitkat.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

After rename the file, I checked whether the file exists or not by pragmatically, the result is file not exists with the new name.

Comment: the name is changed but it doesn't show in the music list of what? your device?

Comment: @orvenito new file is not showing in my mobile, i checked in File browser

Comment: after rename the file , I checked weather the file exists or not by pragmatically, the result is file not exits with the new name @ orvenito

Comment: did you check on the device? maybe just wrong path or something

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to use "adb shell" and "cd /storage/emulated/0/media/audio/music/", then list file and check the files there? Whether the filename has been changed or not?

If the filename changed, then it is an issue of sync in the Music Player.

I have ever met issue that I changed the photo album, but cannot get the changes in my App by get system photo album through content provider. I have no idea how to solve it, and it disappears after phone restarted.

Comment: how  to access the folder "storage/emulated/0/media/audio/music/"

Comment: Connect the phone to PC and type adb shell in command line, then you should be entered shell of your phone. It might need root privilege to enter directory /storage/emulated/0/media/audio/music/